# Hand-written typography

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typography

I'm interested in whats the methods you would use to create a typographic effect similar to this poster (click for larger size)
[image]

The part I'm referring to the the title "7 Letters".

Answer (score 5):

That would be [calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligraphy). From the looks of it, done with [watercolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watercolor_painting) paints.